# How to show solution of two dimensional dynamical system is bounded using Lyapunov function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, lyapunov-functions

Consider the following two dimensional system
$\dot{x_1}=x_2-x_1^3$ ,
$\dot{x_2}=x_1+x_2-2x_2^3$

Using the Lyapunov function
$\operatorname{V}(x)=\frac 12x_1^2+\frac 12x_2^2$
and the Young inequalities
$2x_1x_2 \le x_1^2+x_2^2$
,$2x_1^2x_2^2 \le x_1^4+x_2^4$

prove that every solution of the dynamical system is bounded.

I know that we have to show that $\operatorname{V'}(x)\le-c_1\|x(t)\|^r+L$ for some positive constants r,L.
Another way to go is by showing that $\operatorname{V'}(x)\le-c_1\operatorname{V}^q$ for some positive constants $c_1\ge0,q \ge1$

However I cant find a way to transform the inequality in any of these two ways , so if anyone could give me a hand I would really appreciate it.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You should be able to get $V'\le aV-bV^2$ which gives an inward direction for large values of $V$.

Comment: I managed to find something close to what you are proposing but still I am missing something.I found $\operatorname{V'}(x)  \le -4\operatorname{V^2}(x)+\operatorname{2V}(x)+x_1^4+x_2^2$

Comment: One can use $2xy+y^2\le x^2+2y^2\le 2r^2$ and $x^4+\frac12(2y^2)^2\ge\frac54(x^2+\frac12(2y^2))^2$, the last by the weighted mean inequality.